# Composer update to last commit - Sylius example

Tags: git, github, composer-php, sylius

I installed [Sylius](http://sylius.org/) with composer using following commands:

```
$ wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
$ composer.phar create-project sylius/sylius -s dev
$ cd sylius
$ app/console sylius:install
```

I made some work on application and found that github version is a few commit ahead from my version (I'm using branch `dev-master` / `0.16.x-dev` ) and wanted to update.

I typed `composer update` with ran successfully but my local files weren't update to latest version (worth to mention that sylius is still in the same version `0.16.x-dev`, so there weren't new release by meantime.

Could you tell me how can I update my sources to the latest commit using `composer`?

My `composer.json` file:

```
{
"name":        "sylius/sylius",
"type":        "project",
"description": "E-Commerce platform for PHP, based on Symfony framework.",
"license":     "MIT",
"homepage":    "http://sylius.org",
"authors": [
    {
        "name":     "Paweł Jędrzejewski",
        "homepage": "http://pjedrzejewski.com"
    },
    {
        "name":     "Sylius project",
        "homepage": "http://sylius.org"
    },
    {
        "name":     "Community contributions",
        "homepage": "http://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/contributors"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "ext-exif": "*",
    "ext-fileinfo": "*",
    "ext-gd": "*",

    "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "~2.0",
    "doctrine/collections": "~1.2",
    "doctrine/common": "~2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "~1.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "~2.2",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "~1.0",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.4.8,<2.5",
    "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "^1.3@rc",
    "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "~1.4",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "~1.5",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.2",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "~0.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "jackalope/jackalope": "^1.1.4",
    "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "^1.1.2",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "~0.13",
    "jms/translation-bundle": "~1.1",
    "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle": "~0.1",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~1.1",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "~1.2",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "~1.0",
    "omnipay/omnipay": "~2.3",
    "payum/omnipay-bridge": "~1.0",
    "payum/payum": "~1.0",
    "payum/payum-bundle": "~1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "~5.0",
    "symfony-cmf/block-bundle": "~1.2",
    "symfony-cmf/content-bundle": "~1.2",
    "symfony-cmf/create-bundle": "~1.2",
    "symfony-cmf/media-bundle": "~1.2",
    "symfony-cmf/menu-bundle": "~1.2",
    "symfony-cmf/routing-bundle": "~1.2",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.6",
    "symfony/event-dispatcher": "^2.7",
    "symfony/expression-language": "^2.7",
    "symfony/form": "^2.7",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "^2.7",
    "symfony/intl": "^2.7",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.7",
    "symfony/options-resolver": "^2.7",
    "symfony/property-access": "^2.7",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "^2.7.7",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "^2.7",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "~1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-intl-icu": "~1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "~1.0",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "twig/twig": "~1.11",
    "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "~1.0",
    "willdurand/hateoas-bundle": "~0.4",
    "winzou/state-machine-bundle": "~0.2",
    "ocramius/proxy-manager": "^1.0",
    "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "^2.7"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpspec/phpspec": "^2.4",
    "behat/behat": "~3.0",
    "behat/symfony2-extension": "~2.0",
    "behat/mink-extension": "~2.0",
    "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "~1.2",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "~1.2",
    "behat/mink": "~1.6",
    "akeneo/phpspec-skip-example-extension": "~1.2",
    "coduo/php-matcher": "~1.0",
    "lakion/mink-debug-extension": "^1.0.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.1"
},
"replace": {
    "sylius/addressing":         "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/addressing-bundle":  "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/api-bundle":         "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/archetype":          "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/archetype-bundle":   "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/attribute":          "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/attribute-bundle":   "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/cart":               "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/cart-bundle":        "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/contact":            "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/contact-bundle":     "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/content":            "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/content-bundle":     "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/core":               "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/core-bundle":        "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/currency":           "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/currency-bundle":    "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/fixtures-bundle":    "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/flow-bundle":        "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/installer-bundle":   "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/inventory":          "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/inventory-bundle":   "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/locale":             "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/locale-bundle":      "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/money-bundle":       "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/order":              "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/order-bundle":       "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/payment":            "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/payment-bundle":     "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/payum-bundle":       "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/pricing":            "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/pricing-bundle":     "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/product":            "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/product-bundle":     "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/promotion":          "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/promotion-bundle":   "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/rbac":               "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/rbac-bundle":        "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/registry":           "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/report":             "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/report-bundle":      "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/resource":           "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/resource-bundle":    "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/search":             "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/search-bundle":      "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/sequence":           "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/sequence-bundle":    "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/settings-bundle":    "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/shipping":           "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/shipping-bundle":    "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/storage":            "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/taxation":           "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/taxation-bundle":    "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/taxonomy":           "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/taxonomy-bundle":    "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/translation":        "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/translation-bundle": "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/user":               "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/user-bundle":        "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/variation":          "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/variation-bundle":   "0.16.x-dev",
    "sylius/web-bundle":         "0.16.x-dev"
},
"suggest": {
    "ext-iconv": "For better performance than using Symfony Polyfill Component",
    "ext-intl": "For better performance than using Symfony Polyfill Component",
    "ext-mbstring": "For better performance than using Symfony Polyfill Component"
},
"scripts": {
    "travis-build": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Symfony\\Cmf\\Bundle\\CreateBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::downloadCreateAndCkeditor"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Symfony\\Cmf\\Bundle\\CreateBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::downloadCreateAndCkeditor",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Symfony\\Cmf\\Bundle\\CreateBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::downloadCreateAndCkeditor",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "Sylius\\": "src/" }
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "0.16-dev"
    },
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web"
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your composer.json file?

Comment: so are Sylius files in the vendors or src folder?

Comment: ok, go to src/Sylius and try git pull, let me know if that works.

Comment: @gvf It won't because during installation I choose option "delete git files". But does not  the `replace` part of `composer.json` do exactly that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97639/discussion-between-starspire-and-gvf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to src/Sylius and do git init and then git remote add origin git@github.com:Sylius/Sylius.git
then git pull